# is possible to make html input type number only show numbers which are multiple of 5

Tags: html, input

Is it possible to make html input type number shows only numbers which are multiple of 5 (5,10,15....)?

```
    <input type="number" name="pax">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For HTML 5 only

```
<input type="number" name="pax" step="5">
```

There are other javascript or regex solutions but they shouldn't be necessary.

Further reading on type input:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Here is an example using some more popular attributes of number inputs.

```
<input type="number" name="pax" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="0">
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see my project of the cross-browser filter of value of the text input element on your web page using JavaScript language: [Input Key Filter](https://github.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter) . You can filter the value as an integer number, a float number, or write a custom filter. Code example of html input type number only show numbers which are multiple of 5:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Input Key Filter Test</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <!-- For compatibility of IE browser with audio element in the beep() function.
 https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 To make html input type number only show numbers which are multiple of 5 
<input id="MultipleOf5">
<script>
 function TextAddMultipleOf5(elementInput){
  inputKeyFilter.TextAdd(isRussian() ?
    "разрешается только числа, которые кратны 5. Например: 5 10 15"
    : "only allowed numbers which are multiple of 5. Examples: 5 10 15"
   , elementInput);
 }
 
 function isMultipleOf5(input){
  var integer = parseInt(input.value);
  if(inputKeyFilter.isNaN(integer, input))
   return false;//value is not integer
  if(parseInt(integer/5)*5 != integer)
   return false;//integer is not multiple of 5
  return true;//integer is multiple of 5
 }
 
 inputKeyFilter.Create("MultipleOf5"
  , function(event){//onChange event
   inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
   
   var elementNewMultipleOf5 = document.getElementById("NewMultipleOf5");
   if(isMultipleOf5(this)){
    elementNewMultipleOf5.innerHTML = this.value;
    return;
   }
   elementNewMultipleOf5.innerHTML = "";
   TextAddMultipleOf5(this);
  }
  , function(elementInput, value){//customFilter
   //if(value.match(/^(-?\d*)$/) != null)//value is positive and negative number
   if(value.match(/^(\d*)$/) != null)//value is positive number only
    return true;//value is number
   TextAddMultipleOf5(elementInput);
   return false;//invalid value
  }
  
  //onblur event. Use this function if you want set focus to the input element again if input value is NaN. (empty or invalid)
  , function(event){
   var value;
   if(isMultipleOf5(this))
    value = this.value;
   if(inputKeyFilter.isNaN(parseInt(value), this))
    TextAddMultipleOf5(this);
  }
 );
</script>
 New, multiple of 5 number: <span id="NewMultipleOf5"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Also see my page [of example of the input key filter](https://anhr.github.io/InputKeyFilter/)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have an `onchange` function that takes the id of the number element as an argument, and have it set the element to the rounded to nearest 5 of the current input.

```
function update(id){
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
  value = parseInt(math.round(value/5)*5);
}
```

It could be implemented like:

```
<input type="number" onchange="update(this.id)" id="number-thing" name="pax" step="5">
```

I do not know of a direct way to have it display only multiples, including a typed input. For the numbers, there is a `step` attribute (as seen above) that changes the number to the next highest or lowest multiple of step.

This solution addresses both the increment and decrement buttons, as well as steps of five depending on custom user input.